# Does python have a ruby installer like gem that lets you install modules from the command line even if they are not on your machine?

Tags: python, rubygems

With Ruby you can do gem install  from the command line to install a module...even if it is not on your machine.

Can you do that with python.  Does someone know of a module?

Seth

Comment: Did you really ask a question about nu(bular)? or was that a typo? http://nu.wikispot.org/

Comment: Typo...oops.  I will edit.  Love Nu by the way.
Seth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [`setuptools`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools), which allows you to install packages from [PyPi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi) via `easy_install`. Another option is [`pip`](http://pip.openplans.org/), which also installs from PyPi.

Answer (score 4):

no it does not have a ruby installer that I know of. It does have `easy_install` and `pip` though. Your google-fu is lacking.